# Python - What is wrong with this fucniton declaration?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
def convert(self, path: str):
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i am getting a SyntaxError. I checked online and saw this is how it should be declared. what is wrong with this?

Comment: Looks like either you are missing the code underneath or you have a lot of empty spaces after the function.

Comment: you are missing function body

Comment: as the above comments mentioned you may need to add a function body if you do not have and remove the extra spaces, if its still not working you might need to annotate the method using @ above it with its path

Answer (score 4):

if function defined it must have a code or `pass` instead when you don't want to implement code right now.

```
def foo():
   pass
```

or if you want to warn when function used

```
def foo():
    raise(Exception("NotImplemented"))
```

Comment: You can also use `...` instead of pass, but I agree to this solution.

Comment: yes its called an epsilon

Comment: Actually, it's called ``Ellipsis``. And ``...`` is just short hand for actually writing ``Ellipsis``, which is a globally available constant.

Comment: Oh, you absolutely right, shame on me.

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing in your function just continue your code where I put print().
same with all others things like "if" and "for".

```
def convert(self, path: str):
    print()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).